# How to fix build error when building Linaro GCC crosscompiler crossstool-ng-1.17.0?

Tags: cross-compilation, ubuntu, failure

Crosstool-ng-1.17.0 build-fails-on-ubuntu-12-04.I am getting the below error when i am trying to build crosstool-ng-1.17.0. Please help me to fix the issue.

> shiny@ubuntu:~/crosstool-ng-1.17.0$ ./ct-ng build
>
> [INFO ]  Performing some trivial sanity checks
>
> [INFO ]  Build started 20130117.184001 [INFO ]  Building environment
>   variables
>
> [INFO ]
>
> =================================================================
>
> [INFO ]  Retrieving needed toolchain components' tarballs
>
> [WARN ]    Could not retrieve 'eglibc-2_13'
>
> [ERROR]    [ERROR]  >>
>
> [ERROR]  >>  Build failed in step 'Retrieving needed toolchain
>   components' tarballs'
>
> [ERROR]  >>        called in step '(top-level)'
>
> [ERROR]  >>
>
> [ERROR]  >>  Error happened in:
>   do_libc_get[scripts/build/libc/eglibc.sh@808]
>
> [ERROR]  >>        called from: main[scripts/crosstool-NG.sh@550]
>
> [ERROR]  >>
>
> [ERROR]  >>  For more info on this error, look at the file:
>   'build.log'
>
> [ERROR]  >>  There is a list of known issues, some with workarounds,
>   in:
>
> [ERROR]  >>
>   '/opt/crosstool-ng-1.17.0/share/doc/crosstool-ng/ct-ng.1.17.0/B -
>   Known issues.txt'
>
> [ERROR]
>
> [ERROR]  (elapsed: 0:21.13)
>
> [00:22] / make: *** [build] Error 1

Answer (score 2):

Don't build your own cross-compiler, it's too complicated to get it right. There's a suitable cross-compiler available [here](https://github.com/raspberrypi/tools/tree/master/arm-bcm2708/gcc-linaro-arm-linux-gnueabihf-raspbian).

Answer (score 0):

This may help you:
[Development environment raspberry cross compiler](http://hertaville.com/2012/09/28/development-environment-raspberry-pi-cross-compiler/)